# Allow a single TextBlock in a Button to be updated with the Content leaving others unchanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Lets say i have this Button.

```
<Button Name="MyButton"> 
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="{Binding MyValue1}"/>
        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="{Binding MyValue2}"/>

    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Is it possible in the code to change the Content property without destroying the existing TextBlocks and simply add it as another TextBlock?

```
MyButton.Content = "MyTextHere";
```

Comment: Write your own button template for this.

Comment: @poke And how might one go about doing this?

Comment: Look at [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) in the section called "ItemsControl with data binding"